# How to define the fontsize in a big table?, for all the table

Tags: fontsize

Suppose I am using a big table -- how do I define a fontsize of 8(pt) for the complete table?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{blindtext,mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  3433 &6546546 & 654654 \\
  43423 & 4324342 & 4324234 \\
  654654654 & 654654645 & 654654 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Write `\fontsize{8}{\baselineskip}\selectfont%` before the the `tabular` environment and say `\normalsize` afterwards. If the spacing between the rows are not sufficient, change from `\baselineskip` to another value, say `11pt` or `15pt`

Comment: A big table should be floating. So add `\small` or `\footnotesize` after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @egreg: That's true, but the table in the MWE is not a **big** table really ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I assume it's just a simple example.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but do you agree, that there might occasions where even a big table has to be appear on a specific place?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Use the `center` environment, which provides also some vertical spacing.

Comment: @egreg: I had `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in mind, but that feature was not asked for...

Comment: @egreg , Yes :-) it´s a MWE=simple example :-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. To control the interlines space, I use \setstretch{1.5} because baselineskip gives me not the result I wanted a weeks ago.

Comment: @egreg I must learn what´s "floating´s" It´s so complicated LATEX. I like results, but It´s a hate-love relation :-)

Comment: @MikaIke It's simply a `table` environment. If a table is big, it's unlikely it will find its place precisely at the spot where you'd want it; no problem: it will have a caption and you can refer to it.

Comment: Using `\setstretch` is not so good if you want the contents of the cells to be vertically centred. I would recommend using the `cellspace` package that adds a little vertical space at the top *and* at the bottom of of the cells  when necessary.